# Printing a list of integers from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing

I have a csv file that holds information that I am feeding to a python script. The list stored in the csv looks similar to `['1','2','3','4','5']`. When I create a loop to print out the contents of the list, I get:

```
'(new line)
1(new line)
'(new line)
'(new line)
2(new line)
'(new line)
'(new line)
3(new line)
'(new line)
```

.. until it reaches the end. How can I extract the numerical contents of the list without the parenthesis and brackets? I tried the `.replace()` but when I have numbers higher than 10, it prints out 1 then 0 as if they were two separate values.

Comment: Since you seem to want help with code, _please show us your code that you want help 
with!_. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre]. Welcome to SO

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you list is not stored in proper .csv format. When saving a list of items in a csv file, each of the items should be separated by a single comma. Any other characters will be considered part of the item itself.

In your case when you save `['1','2','3','4','5']` as a csv, the first item becomes `['1'` the second item becomes `'2'` and so on. Try saving the text `1,2,3,4,5` to your csv file.

Comment: I think that might be what the issue is. Thank you for the response. This is my first time making a post to stackoverflow so I apologize for how badly it looks. Im glad you understood what I meant

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have a list from the CSV file:

```
list_example = ["1","2","3","4"]
```

To retrieve items as integer:

```
for i in list_example:
    print(int(i))
```

This will give the result as "int" type:

```
>>1
>>2
>>3
```